# Shader android error: "Invalid version shader"

Tags: java, android, opengl-es

I followed https://stackoverflow.com/a/31095254/6655884 and did the following (added \n line break to version directive)

```
public class OrwellShaders {
    public class Vertex {
        public static final String vertex  = 
            "#version 330 es\n " +
            "layout (location = 0) in vec3 aPos;\n " +
            "layout (location = 1) in vec2 aTexCoord;\n " +
            "\n " +
            "out vec2 TexCoord;\n " +
            "\n " +
            "void main()\n " +
            "{\n " +
            "    gl_Position = vec4(aPos, 1.0);\n " +
            "    TexCoord = vec2(aTexCoord.x, aTexCoord.y);\n " +
            "};\n";
    }
```

but I'm still getting Adreno `error Invalid #version shader`

My phone has Android 8 so it should have support. I'm not using `GLSurfaceView` so there's no `setEGLContextClientVersion(3)` Im just using

```
egl = (EGL10) EGLContext.getEGL();
        eglDisplay = egl.eglGetDisplay(EGL10.EGL_DEFAULT_DISPLAY);
        if (eglDisplay == EGL10.EGL_NO_DISPLAY) {
        //...
```

Comment: The version `#version 330 es` doesn't exist. The most recent GLSL ES version is 3.20 (`#version 320 es`), but there is a desktop GLSL version 3.30  (`#version 330` respectively `#version 330 core`)

Answer (score 1):

Remove "#version 330 es\n". I had a similar error and deleting this made the GLSL compile